# What Segue Is Called On Back Button Click?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I'm going from a table view to details view.

I'm trying to set the title of my tableview in my detailsview segue back to tableview.

I tired calling the same segue that is pushed to details view but no dice.

---

I use

> self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"";

in my details view (to remove the title on the back button)

but when I go back to my TableView it also removes that title....

So I added the following code in my DetailsView segue

> destinationViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Title";

but like I said I think I'm calling the wrong segue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Unwind segue. You need to create method in tableView (not details view) which accept UIStoryboardSegue:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    UIViewController* sourceViewController = segue.sourceViewController;
}
```

After that in storyboard in detail view controller you can see 'exit' icon, this is unwind segue control drag from it to that method and you will create new segue.

Unwind segue is made for deal with this kind of jobs. You can google this to find out more details.

Comment: cant seem to connect "exit" to the ibaction

Comment: Try control drag from back button to the 'exit' icon.

Comment: Oh the back button seems to be automatic...there are no objects for it in my storyboard...I'll have a look

Comment: try cntr drag from file owner or nag item to exit.

Comment: alright, seems to be working -- where can I add the `.navigationItem.title = @"Title";` ?

Comment: You should add it in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppeare in the view controller where you want to change title.

Comment: alright well it's working, though with what seems to be a slight delay -- the reason I was asking about the unwind segue is because it seems the screens are getting their *titles* from the previous views -- so my question what is the best way to set the title of the next screen with the unwind segue?

Comment: Sorry I'm confusing a little bit by next screen you think on the previous one,like table view or next one like details view? You can use title property on view controller, just grab destination or source view controller from segue and set up title property.

Answer (score 0):

Create Segue type "Custom" on your stroyboard. This can be from a button. Create a new UIStoryboardSegue class named "popSegue" In the popSegue.m file add the following;

```
-(void)perform{
    UIViewController *sourceViewContreoller = [self sourceViewController];
    [sourceViewContreoller.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

-In the storyboard editor.

-Select the segue and change the Segue Class to "popSegue"

-Set the Identifier to "popSegue"

Done!

You can use the same "popSegue" class throughout your project.

Hope this helps